# Wordpress query_posts by tag OR category

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to query posts by category or tag? I would like to get the three newest posts that are in the same category OR share the same tag. Below is the code I have already:

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$tags = '';
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $tags .= ','.$tag->name;
  }
} 
$taglist = substr($tags, 1);
$category = get_the_category();
$posts = query_posts('&tag='.$taglist.'&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=3&cat='.$category[0]->term_id);
```

But this only gets posts that are in the same category AND share the same tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this to fetch data twice once for category and then for tag

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$tags = '';
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $tags .= ','.$tag->name;
  }
} 
$taglist = substr($tags, 1);
$category = get_the_category();
$tagposts = query_posts('&tag='.$taglist.'&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=3');

$categoryposts= query_posts('&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=3&cat='.$category[0]->term_id);

$post=array_merge($tagposts,$categoryposts);
```

Then you can use some sort of `array_unique` if have duplicates

Comment: That looks very promising, I think I can query it down from there to remove the duplicates. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tag name, you can use a query like below to get all posts that have a tag name matching it:

```
select id, post_title, guid from wp_posts p inner join wp_term_relationships r 
on p.id=r.object_id and p.post_status='publish' and p.post_type='post' 
inner join wp_term_taxonomy x on r.term_taxonomy_id=x.term_taxonomy_id and 
x.taxonomy='post_tag' inner join wp_terms t on x.term_id=t.term_id and t.name 
like '%tag_name%' group by r.object_id;
```

Substitute the **tag_name** in the query above.
Here is the [reference](http://www.mywebschools.com/wordpress/wordpress-useful-sql-queries/)